# How to open Instagram app from Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm trying to open a perfil directly on instagram app from Ionic.

appAvailability detected that Instagram is available, but when I try to open:

```
window.open("instagram://user?username=" + username, "_blank", "location=yes");
```

The app(ionic) doesn't recognize the "instagram://" and tries to open in browser or inappbrowser(plugin).

I have tried also:

```
  window.open("instagram://user?username=" + username, "_blank", "location=yes");
```

and

```
 $window.open("instagram://user?username=" + username, "_system", "location=no");
```

Nothing works. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: which inAppBrowser plugin version are you using? your last example (_system) should work

Comment: Thanks. I not solved the problem, then I tried in another device and it worked.

Only in Android 4.1.2 the plugin doesn't work(with instagram). I don't no if it's a android or plugin problem.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on iPhone, use the following steps:

1. Add the Cordova Browser Plugin.

`cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git`

2. Add the a link to open Instagram

`<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('instagram://user?username=andrewoodleyjr', '_system'); return false;">
       Instagram 
</a>`

I don't believe Android has a hook like iOS therefore the instagram:// will not work.

Answer (score 3):

**19-06-2021** / Ionic / Angular

This works for me. I have used [App Availability](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability)  and [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) plugins. And
I have used this [article](https://codevampires.com/open-instagram-app-in-ionic-4/).

```
async goToInstagram(instagram:string): Promise<void> {

    let app: string;

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = 'instagram://';

    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = 'com.instagram.android';
    }

    const isAppAvailable: boolean = await this.appAvailability.check(app);

    isAppAvailable?
      this.inAppBrowser.create(`instagram://user?username=${instagram}`, '_system') :
      this.inAppBrowser.create(`https://www.instagram.com/${instagram}`, '_system');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Android has hooks for instagram, twitter and facebook. You must have the apps installed to work.

window.open(link, '_system');

where for posts, the pattern is

```
instagram://media?id=your-post-id
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=your-post-link
twitter://status?id=your-post-id
```